# Showing that sequence converges in distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Consider the following sequence of random variable: $X_{1}$,$X_{2}$,$X_{3}$,$X_{4}$,$X_{5}$, ... i.i.d with $E(X_{i}=\mu)$ and n even.
Define: $P_{n}=\frac{2}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}X_{2i}$ and $I_{n}=\frac{2}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}X_{2i-1}$ the mean of the even and odd terms on the sample.

Suppose we know that: $\sqrt{n} (\overline{X_{n}}-\mu) \sim F$.

Show that $\sqrt{n} (P_{n}-\mu) \sim F$ and $\sqrt{n} (I_{n}-\mu) \sim F$

Any help?

Comment: Do you have more assumptions? If $X_j = (-1)^j$ (deterministic quantities) then I don't think the claim holds.

Comment: @angryavian Hi. I edited. I missed "with $E(X_{i}=\mu)$ and n even number." It will help?

Comment: Are you assuming the r.v.s are i.i.d.?

Comment: @rem Yes the r.v are iid

Comment: If the random variables are independent and identically distributed, then $P_n$ and $I_n$ have the same distribution and they have the same distribution as a subsequence of $\bar X_n.$

Comment: @WillM. Thanks thanks! If it doesnt identically distributed I will have trouble, right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$